# How to compare the similarity of two keras models

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I have built a Keras model using the functional API and I created a second model using `model_from_json()` function. I want to see if the model layers (not the weights) of the two models are exactly the same.

How can I compare the two Keras models?

**EDIT**

Based on the comments below, I could possibly compare each layer. Would something like the one below make sense:

```
for l1, l2 in zip(mdl.layers, mdl2.layers):
    print (l1.get_config() == l2.get_config())
```

Comment: You want to compare them programatically or just by eyes? Is `model.summary()` enough or useful for you?

Comment: I meant programmatically.. I want to check they have the same shapes, regularization etc..

Comment: Maybe you can iterate over layers of models and compare one by one, since you don't care about the weights or how the model is compiled and optimized.

Comment: @AbdulrahmanBres: OK, then how do I compare two Keras layers?

Answer (score 3):

**Update:** your approach is correct.

You can iterate over the two models layers and compare one by one (since you don't care about the weights or how the model is compiled and optimized).

You can do this:

```
for l1, l2 in zip(mdl.layers, mdl2.layers):
    print(l1.get_config() == l2.get_config())
```

Or just:

```
print(mdl.get_config() == mdl2.get_config())
```

Comment: zip will take the shorter of the two

Answer (score -1):

you can use ROC curves to compare classifiers.

With binary classifiers, one calculates the true-positive-rate and the false-positive-rate for all possible thresholds and plots the first on the y-axis and the second on the x-axis. The resulting curve per classifier can be integrated and the resulting integral, the so called "area under the curve", is equal to the probability that the classifier rankes a randomly chosen positive sample higher than a randomly chosen negative one. This value can be used to compare classifiers because a higher value shows a overall better performance than a lower one. Fawcett also gives a method to apply this to multi-class classification

Comment: Vincent, I don't want to compare the statistical performance of the two models. I just want to ensure that the two models are architecturally similar.